# Excel 2010 Unpivot Data or Utilize MySQL for Unpivot

Tags: mysql, excel, select, pivot-table, unpivot

I've got a lot of data in an Excel sheet that I need reformatted.  I am trying to achieve this by using Pivot Table but I'm not sure it is possible.

Here is current data set (SKU is unique currently):
[image: Current Excel Sheet]

I need it to look more like this (where SKU is NOT unique):
[image: New Excel Sheet Needed]

I'm willing to throw my current sheet into a MySQL database and query it if I can figure out a good query to utilize as well.

Any ideas on where to go from here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're wanting to unpivot your data (i.e. turn it from a crosstab into a flat file), although some of your desired output looks weird. Look at my answer to this question: [convert cross table to list to make pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47252860/convert-cross-table-to-list-to-make-pivot-table/47253398#47253398)

Comment: Sounds like something I want to do.  I tried the VBA Tutorial and added the Macro.  It will not unpivot the data though.

Comment: You're gonna have to get more specific than that.

Comment: Followed UnPivot Macro Code from here: http://www.contextures.com/excelunpivotmacro.html.  I entered pipe "|" for to combine labels and "3" for number of cols at the left side of the table. I run it and it says "Could not unpivot the data."

Comment: That's not one of the links I posted at the other thread. Did you read my response there?

Comment: Indeed I had to "unpivot".  I have never done such a thing.  I utilized this method found here though: http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/transposing-a-dataset-with-a-pivottable/

Comment: Awesome. It's even easier with both PowerQuery (aka the "Get & Transform" tab you'll find in Excel 2013 or later) and also the code listing I linked to at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/21/unpivot-shootout/